# JSTL tag replacement for bean:define

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts-1, jstl-functions

I am unable to find replacement for bean:define tag in JSTL.

```
<bean:define id="arraySize" value="<%=String.valueOf(abc.size())%>" scope="request"  />
```

and

```
<bean:define id="abc" name="abcform" property="abc" type="java.util.ArrayList"  />
```

can anyone suggest JSTL replacement for above Struts tags.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're trying to get a value called `abc` from the `abcform`'s `abc` property and it's an array list? You'd have to access the action form directly and might be able to use `<c:set />`, but I probably wouldn't bother--either continue to use the S1 tag, or expose it as a property in the action itself.

Comment: As part of struts to spring migration i was working ... so i got stuck with above code

Comment: did u remember what you applied with JSTL so ?

Comment: No sorry @MychaL